# Resize image iOS React Native

Tags: ios, image, react-native

Does one of you as this problem: I use an image on my **React Native** app, I place it, I resize it, no problem on Android and iOS.

When I generate my IPA file, I put him on the store, easily. But when I download my app from the **App Store**, my image is not the same. It got a wrong size and an incorrect alignment

Can someone explain to me why? I've not this problem on my Android app. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some code? How you render image? What styles you apply?

Comment: Are you referring to your app icon or an image in one of your screens inside your react native app?

Comment: @inferus-vv Find the solution (I think), my style is : 'resizeMode: center', I think I need to do 'resizeMode: contain' and it can work